# How to append to existing documents using mongoimport and csv files

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use mongoimport to translate a one-to-many relational structure into mongoDB using csv files.  My approach is to import the "one" file then use the upsert option to append the "many" records as a nested array but it looks like it only replaces the original document instead of appending.

Is this a limitation of mongoimport or could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that mongoimport would append?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do [upserts when using mongoimport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-Example%3aImportingwith%7B%7Bupsert%7D%7D), but you cannot use complex operators to perform modifications to the data as you would with a normal update operation.  This is a limitation of mongoimport - essentially each piece of data you import must be insert ready even though you are using the upsert functionality, which is basically working as a de-duplication mechanism for your input data.

If you wish to merge in a more sophisticated manner then it would be best to use one of [the drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) and merge the data using your language of choice.  This also has the advantage of avoiding potential issues with [type fidelity](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/import-export/#data-type-fidelity) and allowing you to code around exceptions etc.

Comment: Thanks Adam.  I guess it was wishful thinking that I could use the import utility.